# Notations used in probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across a question in which the interval of the the domain of a cumulative distribution function was given in the form 
[image: Quesrion]

What does the circle with a line are called and what difference is between a normal inequality sign and this?

Comment: This may be a typographical error on the publisher's part.

Comment: Is it clear? It looks like a circle with a slashed line across it.

Comment: It's just speculation. There shouldn't be any other symbols for inequalities other than the ones we know. I suggest finding other places where there are inequalities (or should be) and compare.